A question on expectation of exponential of indicator function and random variables

This is the equation 7.4.27 from Shreve’s stochastic calculus book 2.
I’m confuse with deriving the equation from the picture. Here we can treat the risk-neutral measure as the usual probability measure as it doesn't affect to my question.
I try to derive it step-by-step as follow:
Given $\sigma >0$. Let $A$ be the event $$A:=\left\{\sigma\hat M(\tau)-\mathrm{log}\dfrac{y}{x}>0\right\}= \left\{\hat M(\tau)>\dfrac{1}{\sigma}\mathrm{log}\dfrac{y}{x}\right\} $$ Then
$$g(x,y)=\tilde{\mathbb{E}}\mathrm{exp}\left\{\left[\sigma\hat M(\tau)-\mathrm{log}\dfrac{y}{x}\right]^+\right\}= \tilde{\mathbb{E}}\mathrm{exp}\left\{1_A\left[\sigma\hat M(\tau)+\mathrm{log}\dfrac{x}{y}\right]\right\}= \tilde{\mathbb{E}}\left(\mathrm{exp}\left\{1_A\left[\sigma\hat M(\tau)\right]\right\}\cdot \mathrm{exp}\left\{1_A\left[\mathrm{log}\dfrac{x}{y}\right]\right\}\right)
$$
I think this should almost give the second summand on 7.4.27 if continues. One problem is that, from the picture, how come $x/y$ appears because of the occurrence of A but $1_A$ is still inside the second expectation?
Moreover, i got no idea how the first summand from the picture came out.
Thank you.

Hint
For all r.v. $X$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\big[e^{X^+}\big]&=\mathbb E\Big[\mathbb E\big[e^{X\boldsymbol 1_{\{X\geq 0\}}}\mid \boldsymbol 1_{\{X\geq 0\}}\big]\Big]\\
&=\underbrace{\mathbb E\big[e^X\mid X\geq 0\big]\mathbb P\{X\geq 0\}}_{=\mathbb E[X\boldsymbol 1_{\{X\geq 0\}}]}+\underbrace{\mathbb E\big[e^{0X}\mid X\leq 0\big]}_{=1}\mathbb P\{X\leq 0\}\\
&=\mathbb E\big[e^X\boldsymbol 1_{\{X\geq 0\}}\big]+\mathbb P\{X\leq 0\},
\end{align*}
as wished.

This really helps but I’m wondering why $1_\left{X \geq 0\right} $instead of $1_\left{X > 0\right}$? What i’m thinking is that $X^+$ is nonzero when  $X>0$. Is it because we’re now considering $e^{X^+}$?

Because when $X=0$, you have that $X^+=X=0$. In fact, $X^+$ is defined as $\max{X,0}$.

Sorry I know you’re correct but I still got a little bit confused. Isn’t there a chance that $X1_{{X \geq 0}}$ will be zero? So if we take the expectation then it can be zero, but aren’t people usually do want to ignore the part that contribute zero to the expectation (or Lebesgue integral)? So that’s why I’m asking if we should use $X1_{{X > 0}}$. I’m wondering the reason why writing $X1_{{X \geq 0}}$ is because $e^{X1_{{X \geq 0}}}$ is always nonzero even if $X1_{{X \geq 0}}$ is zero. Not sure if this is a sound reasoning or not.

Yes of course : $\mathbb P{X\boldsymbol 1_{{X\geq 0}}=0}=\mathbb P{X\leq 0}$. Notice that $$\mathbb P{X\boldsymbol 1_{{X>0}}=0}=\mathbb P{X\boldsymbol 1_{{X\geq 0}}=0}=\mathbb P{X\leq 0}.$$
Moreover, $e^{X}$ will never be $0$ even if $X<0$... so I don't understand your point with $X\boldsymbol 1_{{X\geq 0}}$.

I’ve got you now. I forgot about $$\mathbb{P}{X1_{{{X \geq 0}} = 0} = \mathbb{P}{X \leq 0}$$
